# How is a 24-bit audio stream delivered to the graph?

Tags: audio, directshow, audio-streaming

This is probably a very silly question, but after searching for a while, I couldn't find a straight answer.

If a source filter (such as the  LAV Audio codec) is processing a 24-bit integral audio stream, how are individual audio samples delivered to the graph?
(for simplicity lets consider a monophonic stream)

**Are they stored individually on a 32-bit integer with the most-significant bits unused, or are they stored in a packed form, with the least significant bits of the next sample occupying the spare, most-significant bits of the current sample?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format is similar to 16-bit PCM: the values are signed integers, little endian.

With 24-bit audio you normally define the format with the help of [`WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757714) structure, as opposed to `WAVEFORMATEX` (well, the latter is also possible in terms of being accepted by certain filters, but in general you are expected to use the former).

The structure has two values: number of bits per sample and number of valid bits per sample. So it's possible to have the 24-bit data represented as 24-bit values, and also as 24-bit meaningful bits of 32-bit values. The payload data should match the format.

There is no mix of bits of different samples within a byte:

> However, wBitsPerSample is the container size and **must be a multiple of 8**, whereas wValidBitsPerSample can be any value not exceeding the container size. For example, if the format uses 20-bit samples, wBitsPerSample must be at least 24, but wValidBitsPerSample is 20.

To my best knowledge it's typical to have just 24-bit values, that is three bytes per PCM sample.

Non-PCM formats might define different packing and use "unused" bits more efficiently, so that, for example, to samples of 20-bit audio consume 5 bytes.

Comment: I was strongly expecting an answer from you Roman ;)  You are definitely The authority in all things related to Windows Media. Cheers!